# Add class to nearest tr with jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to add class to nearest tr using jquery but its not working, Below is my html code

```js
$(function() {
  $('span.disabled-status').closest('tr').addClass('sales-row');
});
```

```css
.sales-row { color: #C00; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td width="8%" class="">
      <div class="text-left">615</div>
    </td>
    <td width="8%" class="">
      <div class="text-left">Nichole</div>
    </td>
    <td width="8%" class="">
      <div class="text-left">Fredericka Carrillo</div>
    </td>
    <td width="8%" class="">
      <div class="text-left">Lyle Lloyd</div>
    </td>
    <td width="8%" class="">
      <div class="text-left">qiqa@mailinator.com</div>
    </td>
    <td width="8%" class="">
      <div class="text-left">870</div>
    </td>
    <td width="8%" class="">
      <div class="text-left">392</div>
    </td>
    <td width="8%" class="">
      <div class="text-left">قيد الانتظار</div>
    </td>
    <td width="8%" class="sorted">
      <div class="text-left"><span class="disabled-status">Value here </span></div>
    </td>
    <td align="left" width="20%">
      some content here
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

This table is dynamically generated and class disabled-status is added to few of the records i want to apply this class to tr using jQuery

I tried below code that's not working :

```
$(function(){ $('span.disabled-status').closest('tr').addClass('sales-row');});
```

can someone help pls to sort the issue

Comment: Your code is valid, and works in the snippet where the `table` content is available when the page loads. The issue is because, as you state, '*This table is dynamically generated*', as such you need to run your code *after* the table has been added to the DOM. Exactly how you do that will depend on the code which is performing that action, and what access you have to it

Comment: thanks for your reply @RoryMcCrossan, yes you are right wrapped it inside settimout and it worked Thanks for your help :-)

Comment: Glad it helped, but just note that `setTimeout()` isn't a workable solution. If you're loading the content via AJAX use a callback/promise, if it's loaded from an external library, listen for any events it raises

Comment: actually table is rendered using Grocery crud and classes are added while using javascript before